# Number of points in polygon not equal in QGIS and Geopandas

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have polygons and points.

What I do is a very simple operation - count points in the polygon. Primary I am working in Python, however I use QGIS to check and visualize the results.

I have this code where I using GeoPandas Spatial Join and a loop to find which point belongs to which small polygon. To check I did the same thing in QGIS using `Count Points in Polygon` tool, but the number of points are a little different from the result I obtained with Python.

```
import geopandas as gpd

polygons = gpd.read_csv(r'E:\...\Polygons.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\points.shp')

points_join = gpd.sjoin(points, polygons)[['polygon_ID', 'point_Ht', 'point_D', 'geometry']]

for idx, val in polygons.index:
    df_p = points_join[points_join['polygon_ID'] == val]
    
    number_of_points = df_p['polygon_ID'].count()

    polygons.loc[idx, 'NumberPoints'] = number_of_points
```

Here is the point count using both methods, and as we can see that there are no significant differences between both methods, however the number of points do not match.

[image]

[image]

Has anyone has experienced something similar working with counting points in polygon in Python and QGIS? At first I assumed that the problem could be the coordinate system, however I use the same files with the same CRS each time.

Comment: "In" and "On" are different relationships. Have you checked to see if the "missing" points aren't really *within* any polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same count in geopandas and QGIS. Your code is a bit complicated, try using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import geopandas as gpd

dfpoint = gpd.read_file(filename=r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/1000points.shp')
dfpoly = gpd.read_file(filename=r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/polygons.shp')
dfsjoin = gpd.sjoin(left_df=dfpoly, right_df=dfpoint, how='left') #Left or polygons with zero points are discarded
dfcount = dfsjoin.groupby('polyid')['pointid'].count().rename('pointcount').reset_index()

#   polyid  pointcount
#0       1          97
#1       2          70
#2       3           0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@BERA answer is correct and works smoothly, however as I need the loop for further calculations I found another way simply adding `op = 'within'` when joining points and polygons, like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

polygons = gpd.read_csv(r'E:\...\Polygons.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\points.shp')

points_join = gpd.sjoin(points, polygons, op='within')

for idx in polygons.index:
    df_p = points_join[points_join['polygon_ID'] == idx]
    
    number_of_points = df_p['polygon_ID'].count()

    polygons.loc[idx, 'NumberPoints'] = number_of_points
```

Point number matches QGIS!